# Error "El objeto que acepta valores Null debe tener un valor" cuando recorro Listado en foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un método que almacena una **lista de Clientes** y cuando lo quiero recorrer en mi vista me da el error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'El objeto que acepta valores Null
>   debe tener un valor.'

Mi clase Cliente:

```
 public partial class Cliente
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Cliente()
        {
            this.Rel_Reserva_Asiento = new HashSet<Rel_Reserva_Asiento>();
            this.Ticket = new HashSet<Ticket>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TipoDocumentoId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Documento { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
        public string Domicilio { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LocalidadId { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Alta { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SexoId { get; set; }
        public string passwd { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Rel_Reserva_Asiento> Rel_Reserva_Asiento { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Ticket { get; set; }
    }
}
```

y mi método :

```
 public List<Cliente> buscarCliente(Pasajero pasajero)
        {
            List<Cliente> Totalclientes = new List<Cliente>();

            foreach (int dni in pasajero.dni)
            {


                Cliente cliente = ctx.Cliente.First(x => x.Documento == dni);


                if (cliente != null)
                {

                    Totalclientes.Add(cliente);
                }
                else
                {

                }

            }

                return Totalclientes;

        }
```

El método funciona perfecto, llega a la vista con los clientes. pero cuando recorro la lista de los clientes me tira el error ya mencionado.

```
@if (ViewBag.clientes != null)
                {
            <form method="post" action="/Home/buscarClientes">
                @foreach (Cliente cliente in ViewBag.clientes)
                {

                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5>Pasajero @cliente.Nombre  @cliente.Apellido</h5>
                    <p id="carga"></p>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="dni" name="dni" value="@cliente.Documento" readonly />
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" value="@cliente.Telefono" readonly />
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" value="@cliente.SexoId.Value" readonly />
                </div>


                }
            </form>
                }
```

Busque información pero no encontré mucho. Agradecería el aporte!

Gracias!

Comment: Seguramente o Documento o SexoId que son Nulleable no tiene informacion, y como vemos es mas que nada SexoId porque quieres acceder al SexoId.Value. entonces la pregunta: ¿Que quieres hacer cuando algunos de estos dos es null? tener un valor por default o ni siquiera renderizar el input? Y otra pregunta mas general. ¿cual es el requerimiento para el form que hace post a "/Home/buscarClientes"? Asi podemos ver que campos necesitas para enviar al otra pagina. Ya que con el "Id" seria suficiente para buscar, pero por eso consulto la funcionalidad/requerimiento

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo estás teniendo en las propiedades del tipo **`Nullable<T>`** de la Clase `Cliente`, y más en concreto en `Nullable<int> Documento` y `Nullable<int> SexoId`.

En La Vista debes acceder a ellas mediante la propiedad `GetValueOrDefault()`, por si el valor devuelto es NULL.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="dni" name="dni" value="@cliente.Documento.GetValueOrDefault()" readonly />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" value="@cliente.Telefono" readonly />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Sexo" name="Sexo" value="@cliente.SexoId.GetValueOrDefault()" readonly />
```